# Shortwave Fixed Frequency Modulator

Tags: frequency, oscilloscope

I am a newbie in electronics and have come up with a modulator for shortwave fixed frequency (27.125 MHz). I have simulated the circuit in Multisim but I don't know exactly if it is really working as it is supposed to or not. Any help shall be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I have added the schematics and OSC graph.[image: Shortwave Fixed Frequency Modulator Schematics][image: Shortwave Fixed Frequency Modulator OSC Graph]

Comment: Just demodulate the signal or do an FFT analysis around 27 MHz.

Comment: Try setting the scope timebase to 1 ms overall

Comment: Thank you both Antonio51 and Andy aka. When I set the time base to 1 ms; scope gets painfully slow.

Comment: Persevere with what I suggested. I mean, I asked 12 minutes ago and you came back 3 or 4 minutes later and said it was painfully slow. Some simulations can take several minutes to complete. 15 minutes maximum is my personal limit though.

Comment: LOL Andy aka! I agree and will persevere with it, sir.

Comment: Awais - Modulating a 27 MHz carrier with 1kHz *does require* a painfully-slow simulation run. You can speed it up by increasing 1kHz voltage source to 100 kHz, or even 1 MHz. Then your oscilloscope time span can be reduced substantially, which will allow a shorter simulation run.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Glen_Geek sir. I'll follow your advice right away!